# jmeter is generating a dynamic boundary in request

Tags: jmeter

I have been trying to run a script associated with file upload using JMeter. Everytime, I run the script, the script fails with '404 Not Found' in the response. After a detailed analysis on the request generated in 'View Results Tree', i found out that the boundary value is generated dynamically every time i run the script (i am not sure if this is causing the issue).
I have tried below steps:

1. Defined the boundary in 'HTTP Header Manager' by setting "Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryp9kjnMqqJinub6Us" and unchecked 'use multipart/form-data for POST' in the HTTP Request (Parameter and File Upload tabs) and ran the script
   Result: 404 Not Found 
   I still see the dynamic boundaries generated in the request from the result tree
2. Did not define boundary in 'HTTP Header Manager' and checked 'use multipart/form-data for POST' in the HTTP Request (Parameter and File Upload tabs) and ran the script
   Result: 404 Not Found 
   I see the dynamic boundaries generated in the request from the result tree

Other Notes related to request data: My HTTP Request data contains data in parameters and file upload tabs. Used Relative File Path (file exist in jmeter bin). I cannot enter the boundary information in HTTP Request body since I have the data in HTTP Request parameters and file upload tabs

Please advise on how to handle with dynamic boundaries and to make the file upload script successful. Greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Status Code 404 stands for [Not Found](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404), most likely your URL path is not correct, please double check it.

Going forward the easiest way is just recording your file upload request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), just copy the file to JMeter's "bin" folder and record the request using browser via JMeter's proxy - JMeter will generate the relevant [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler. You can add parameterization later on if required.

See [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more detailed information on JMeter configuration for file upload events recording.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri T for your response. I exactly followed the same steps that you have mentioned in your comment prior to posting my original issue. I used 'HTTP Test Script Recorder' to record the file upload scenario (file was in bin folder), copied the steps to my thread group, then ran the thread group. Here, all my other steps in the thread group that does not involve file upload are passed, except the one that involves file upload (incase if the assumption is if i am giving something wrong in the URL).

Comment: Is there any way i can share my screen captures here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with removing content-type from your header and let jmeter handle that. Make sure you have checked the mulipart.